# With a one-to-many relation, how do you get every row of table A if table B doesn't reference some rows of A?

Tags: mysql, join

To simplify my situation, I have two tables: `blogs(id, title, content, ...)` and `blogtags(blogid, tagid)` in mysql. `blogtags` has a many-to-one relation to `blogs` where `blogtags.blogid` is a foreign key to `blogs.id`. Pretty basic.

I have a query that returns one row for every blog and mashes all the tag ids into a single column:

```
SELECT blogs.*, GROUP_CONCAT(blogtags.tagid) as tagids FROM blogs
    JOIN blogtags ON blogs.id=blogtags.blogid 
    GROUP BY blogs.id;
```

This works fine except that some blogs have no tags (there are some blogs with no `blogtags` rows). So, those blogs get completely ignored by the join.

```
INSERT INTO blogs(id, title, content) VALUES(1, 'Blog1', 'one'), (2, 'Blog2', 'two');
INSERT INTO blogtags(blogid, tagid) VALUES(1, 4), (1, 7);
```

*(I'm only inserting the blog ids manually for demostration, of course)*

With that data set, the select query will only grab a row containing the first blog:

```
(id, title, content, tagids)
----------------------------
(1, 'Blog1', 'one', '4,7')
```

**I would like to include every row of `blogs` and just have tagids be an empty string (or something equivalent) if there are no associated tags.**

```
(id, title, content, tagids)
----------------------------
(1, 'Blog1', 'one', '4,7')
(2, 'Blog2', 'two', '') # or tagids could be null or something
```

How would I modify my select statement to get this to work? And also what is this operation called? It seems like it might be a common one, imao.

Here's a fiddle with a more fleshed out example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/633f4/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a left join, which will prevent removing any blogs which happen to have no tags.

```
SELECT
    b.id,
    COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(bt.tagid), 'no tags available') AS tagids
FROM blogs b
LEFT JOIN blogtags bt
      ON b.id = bt.blogid 
GROUP BY
    b.id;
```

Note that I use `COALESCE` to display an appropriate message for those blogs which have no tags.

Comment: *sigh* That's it... Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure there is a duplicate question like this since the solution is so simple.

Comment: Well...the question then is whether there is an _exact_ duplicate.  Your table and its data may be unique to your question.

Comment: True, I'm sure someone will find a way to label this as a duplicate, lol. I'll accept your answer as soon as it allows me to do so.